LXD Networking, LXC Containers in a different subnet don't reply
I have a network 10.0.0.0/24. In this network I have the following machines that matter for the question:

10.0.0.207 - my Ubuntu Server LXD Host
10.0.0.215 - my Firewall, and the default gateway for 10.0.0.0/24
10.0.0.104 - my Laptop

Now I want to create a subnet for my LXD Containers, 10.100.0.0/24 I want to do this, so that I do not have an overlapping subnet for the normal LAN and the LXD Containers.

These LXD Containers should be reachable from 10.0.0.0/24 and should also be able to reach anything in 10.0.0.0/24

So on my firewall (default gateway) i added a static route, destination: 10.100.0.0/24 via 10.0.0.207. i also added rules on my firewall, that everything is allowed from 10.0.0.0 to 10.100.0.0 and vice versa
if i ping 10.100.45 (a running Ubuntu lxd container) from my laptop 10.0.0.104, my packets are lost. I also can't tracert
However, if I tcpdump, everything seems to reach the destination correctly. I also see on my firewall that the request went through:
tcpdump on my LXD Host for the container:
sudo tcpdump -i lxdbr0 host 10.100.0.45
tcpdump: verbose output suppressed, use -v[v]... for full protocol decode
listening on lxdbr0, link-type EN10MB (Ethernet), snapshot length 262144 bytes
11:56:04.012029 IP _gateway > 10.100.0.45: ICMP echo request, id 10005, seq 100, length 40
11:56:04.012066 IP 10.100.0.45 > _gateway: ICMP echo reply, id 10005, seq 100, length 40
11:56:08.863895 IP _gateway > 10.100.0.45: ICMP echo request, id 10005, seq 101, length 40
11:56:08.863930 IP 10.100.0.45 > _gateway: ICMP echo reply, id 10005, seq 101, length 40
11:56:09.217011 ARP, Request who-has 10.100.0.45 tell service-ubu-01, length 28
11:56:09.217001 ARP, Request who-has service-ubu-01 tell 10.100.0.45, length 28
11:56:09.217065 ARP, Reply service-ubu-01 is-at 00:16:3e:08:e6:59 (oui Unknown), length 28
11:56:09.217071 ARP, Reply 10.100.0.45 is-at 00:16:3e:34:16:e0 (oui Unknown), length 28
11:56:13.855060 IP _gateway > 10.100.0.45: ICMP echo request, id 10005, seq 102, length 40
11:56:13.855097 IP 10.100.0.45 > _gateway: ICMP echo reply, id 10005, seq 102, length 40
11:56:18.867026 IP _gateway > 10.100.0.45: ICMP echo request, id 10005, seq 103, length 40
11:56:18.867059 IP 10.100.0.45 > _gateway: ICMP echo reply, id 10005, seq 103, length 40

tcpdump inside my lxd container:
tcpdump -i eth0 icmp
tcpdump: verbose output suppressed, use -v[v]... for full protocol decode
listening on eth0, link-type EN10MB (Ethernet), snapshot length 262144 bytes
11:56:59.301478 IP _gateway > netbird-lxc-01.lxd: ICMP echo request, id 43339, seq 104, length 40
11:56:59.301504 IP netbird-lxc-01.lxd > _gateway: ICMP echo reply, id 43339, seq 104, length 40
11:57:03.858442 IP _gateway > netbird-lxc-01.lxd: ICMP echo request, id 43339, seq 105, length 40
11:57:03.858467 IP netbird-lxc-01.lxd > _gateway: ICMP echo reply, id 43339, seq 105, length 40
11:57:08.859181 IP _gateway > netbird-lxc-01.lxd: ICMP echo request, id 43339, seq 106, length 40
11:57:08.859205 IP netbird-lxc-01.lxd > _gateway: ICMP echo reply, id 43339, seq 106, length 40
^C
6 packets captured
6 packets received by filter
0 packets dropped by kernel

So it seems it's no problem to reach the container, however, the stuff is not sent back to my machine. I also can't see anything on my Firewall from the lxd subnet 10.100.0.0/24 to LAN 10.0.0.0/24 - however pinging my laptop from inside the lxd container works:
root@netbird-lxc-01:~# ping 10.0.0.104
PING 10.0.0.104 (10.0.0.104) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from 10.0.0.104: icmp_seq=1 ttl=127 time=0.658 ms
64 bytes from 10.0.0.104: icmp_seq=2 ttl=127 time=1.52 ms

if i manually add the route on my Windows laptop, i get a response. If I don't add this route I don't get a response.
route add 10.100.0.0 MASK 255.255.255.0 10.0.0.207 METRIC 1
 ping 10.100.0.45

Pinging 10.100.0.45 with 32 bytes of data:
Reply from 10.100.0.45: bytes=32 time<1ms TTL=63
Reply from 10.100.0.45: bytes=32 time<1ms TTL=63
Reply from 10.100.0.45: bytes=32 time=1ms TTL=63
Reply from 10.100.0.45: bytes=32 time<1ms TTL=63

However i don't want to manually add this on all computers, i'd like my default gateway to handle this.
Do i have an error somewhere? Would you suggest a completely different approach?
